# how to ignore an unknown column in super csv

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I m using super csv's bean reader to read my csv files. It works fine if the POJO and columns match.

For eg My pojo has theses values.

```
//They have getters and setters.
//just to make it simple I have used public.
public myPojo
{
 public columnA;
 public columnB;
}
```

My super csv code looks like this.

```
        final String[] header = beanReader.getHeader(true);
        int amountOfColumns=beanReader.length();
        CellProcessor[] processor = new CellProcessor[amountOfColumns];
```

so if my csv files looked like this it works fine.

**columnA,columnB**

value1,value2

but if my csv files had an extra column, It fails with this exception 
check that the corresponding nameMapping element matches the field name in the bean. Can I avoid this exception and just ignore this column. Basically it says it could not find the corresponding setter.

**unknownColumn,columnA,columnB**

someValue,value1,value2

Comment: what is `super csv` ?

Comment: http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html

Comment: Gee, they even have an example http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_reading_variable_cols.html

Comment: but in the example they know the column names.

Comment: @user1364861 Please edit your Question for adding clarifications rather than posting as comments.

Answer (score 1):

I used listReader instead of bean reader. got the column values to a map and I was able to do something like this.

```
protected MyPojo getBeanFromMap(MyPojo MyPojo, Class objClass,
                                    Map<String, String> rowMap)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
{
    Field[] fields = objClass.getFields();
    for(Field f : fields){
        String fieldName = f.getName();
        String value = rowMap.get(fieldName);
        MyPojo.setField(fieldName, value);
    }
    return  MyPojo;
}

public void setField(String fieldName, Object value)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
{
    Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.set(this, value);
}
```